# How to save excel workbook in normal mode with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am opening an Excel with openpyxl library, however it is saving the Excel in read - only mode

I tried the answer of this question:

[Openpyxl does not close Excel workbook in read only mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416842/openpyxl-does-not-close-excel-workbook-in-read-only-mode)

```
wb._archive.close()
```

but it give me AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute '_archive'.

I am working with the following code:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.create_sheet("mysheet", 0)
sheet1 = wb["mysheet"]   
sheet1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = '123'
sheet1.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'summary'
wb.save(filename) /*filename has the adress of xlsx*/
```

The Excel file is created without problem, however it is in 'read only' mode. How can I prevent this? Is there an option for the save or create method to avoid read only mode?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by read-only mode?

Comment: When I open the Excel is in read only mode.

Comment: read-only means your file is being written while you are trying to open.  so you need to close it. in your code like `wb._archive.close()
`

Comment: This solution does not work for me. It gives me: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute '_archive'.

Comment: then try only `wb.close()`

Comment: I add wb.close() after save, but file is still in read only mode.

Comment: I suspect the problem is simply one of file permissions in Windows. Read-only mode in openpyxl have nothing to do with this and is not relevant here. Check the permissions and ownership of the file you've created and that it is not opened by any other program or process.

Comment: Indeed, it was Windows permissions, because I was save it in a folder in C:\. Please @CharlieClark post your comment as an answer to mark as correct for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is simply one of file permissions in Windows. Read-only mode in openpyxl have nothing to do with this and is not relevant here. Check the permissions and ownership of the file you've created and that it is not opened by any other program or process.

Comment: is it possible to modify while it is opened?